# Sorting the given books by their price using Struct

Tags: c, struct

We enter the book's name which only contains 3 letters, its page number, and its price. My algorithm should sort the books by their price(ascending). However, my function gives the wrong input and only sorts once or twice. Struct must be used in this question and only the functions in stdlib or stdio library.

I tried to use bubble sort with price, page count, and names. I used `strcpy` to swap names. However, it seems like it didn't work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Book{
    char name[3];
    int pagecount;
    int price;
};

void sorter(struct Book books[], int n){
    int pass;
    int temp;
    char temp1[3];
    int temp3;
    int i;

    for(pass=1;pass<n;pass++){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(books[i].price> books[i+1].price){
                temp=books[i].price;
                books[i].price= books[i+1].price;
                books[i+1].price=temp;
                strcpy(temp1,books[i].name);
                strcpy(books[i].name,books[i+1].name);
                strcpy(books[i+1].name,temp1);
                temp3= books[i].pagecount;
                books[i].pagecount= books[i+1].pagecount;
                books[i+1].pagecount=temp3;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d- %s: %d pages.", i+1, books[i].name,books[i].pagecount);
        puts("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct Book books[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%3s%d%d",&books[i].name, &books[i].pagecount, &books[i].price);
    }

    sorter(books,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3
LOT 528 10
MSB 340 7
TGH 727 8
```

Expected output:

```
1- MSB: 340 pages.
2- THG: 727 pages.
3- LOT: 528 pages.
```

Actual output:

```
1- MSB: 340 pages.
2- : 0 pages.
3- TGH: 727 pages.
```

Comment: You can copy structures by just assignment, like e.g. `struct Book temp_book = books[i]; books[i] = books[i + 1]; books[i + 1] = temp_book;`.

Comment: Oh and the loop condition `i < n`, think about what happens with the index `i + 1` when `i == n - 1`.

Comment: And if the assignment/exercise isn't about sorting yourself, then use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) to do the sorting for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've tried everything you said except qsort and it didn't work, unfortunately. I'm still getting the same output. I can't use qsort in exams as they're not in our curriculum.

Comment: Your bubblesort is not a bubblesort, `for (pass = 0; pass < n; pass++) { for (i = pass+1; i < n; i++) { if (books[pass].price > books[i].price) { struct Book tmp = books[pass]; books[pass] = books[i]; books[i] = tmp; }}}` You fail to check the return of `scanf`. Your read into `&books[i].name` is wrong it is already a pointer so you should have `books[i].name`. Now it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always enable compiler warnings and errors. The compiler is your friend, not your enemy!

You have several errors in your code:

- off-by-one: your book name is a string with 3 letters, which requires a `char[4]` to store as C strings have a string terminator
- off-by-one: your inner-most loop runs until `i = n - 1` which means your code accesses `books[i + 1] = books[n]`, i.e. one element after the end of the array.
- wrong address: wrong pointer for the `scanf("%3s...)` item, hence the book title is written somewhere into the memory, but not where it is intended

Fixing those, simplifying the swap code and skipping unnecessary passes in the bubble sort results in the following code which gives the expected output for the given input.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Book{
    char name[4]; /* 3 letters + terminator */
    unsigned int pagecount;
    unsigned int price;
};

void sorter(struct Book *books, unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int pass;

    /* bubble up sort */
    for (pass = 1; pass < n; pass++) {
        unsigned int i;

        /*
         * each pass bubbles one book up, therefore we don't
         * need to include that book in further passes
         */
        for (i = 0; i < n - pass; i++) {
            if (books[i].price > books[i+1].price) {
                /* swap */
                struct Book temp = books[i];
                books[i]         = books[i+1];
                books[i+1]       = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (pass = 0; pass < n; pass++) {
        printf("%u- %s: %u pages.\n", pass+1, books[pass].name, books[pass].pagecount);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned int n;
    if (scanf("%u", &n) < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect input for # of books\n");
        return(1);
    }

    struct Book books[n];
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%3s%u%u",
                  books[i].name,
                  &books[i].pagecount,
                  &books[i].price) < 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect input for book #%u\n", i+1);
            return(1);
        }
    }

    sorter(books, n);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Now it should be less wonky bubble sort.

Comment: Yep agreed. The use of a `temp` struct given all members are declared with automatic storage duration makes much more sense than swapping individual members.